# Is there any possibility to transfer data from Azure data lake gen2 to Azure event hub by using Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

Is there any possibility to transfer data from Azure data lake gen2 to Azure event hub by using Azure data factory? Is there any alternative ways to to preserve same folder structure in  Event hub once transfer to Event hub from Data Lake?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.What documentation did you read and what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Data Factory support Azure data lake gen2 but doesn't support Azure event hut now.
Please see  [Azure Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview).
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Event Hubs – Capture is to store events that came in by the Event Hubs. Not what to OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct connection to Event Hub, but you can use [this service](http://nnmer.github.io/azure-services-map/) to see what IO direct endpoints are available and use the *IO tree* to see how you can connect multiple services

Comment: Thanks for reply. above service i can see all input and output service in  a tree